# Select dropdown and checkboxes conflict when removing/adding divs to the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is a hard problem to explain but I'll try as best I can.

I have a container `div` of cards, each card has a colour and a type which is inserted dynamically using PHP:

[image: div container of cards]

Next to this container `div` I have a 'refine' widget with `input` checkboxes for the different colours and a `select` dropdown for the different types.

At the moment I have them both working individually - albeit with some messy code.

**But my problem** is how to make them function correctly **at the same time**, e.g if 'lands' is selected then only the cards with 'type-land' are displayed and depending on which 'colour' checkboxes are checked only the cards that have both 'type-land' **and** the corresponding colour(s) are displayed.

Colour checkboxes working as expected:

[image: only blue cards are displayed with the blue checkbox checked]

Type dropdown working as expected:

[image: only land type cards are being displayed with the lands dropdown option selected]

Both together conflicting with each other somewhere (notice how 'blue instants' are also showing when only 'lands' is selected):

[image: conflict when using both]

PHP refine widget (checkboxes and dropdown):

```
<div class="cat-nav-container">
  <div class="cat-nav-main ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
    <p>Refine your <span>search</span>:</p>
    <label for="checkbox">Colours<span>:</span></label>
    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkbox white">
        <label for="checkbox">White<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="white-checkbox"
          id="white"
          value="white"
          checked
        />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox blue">
        <label for="checkbox">Blue<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="blue-checkbox"
          id="blue"
          value="blue"
          checked
        />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox black">
        <label for="checkbox">Black<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="black-checkbox"
          id="black"
          value="black"
          checked
        />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox red">
        <label for="checkbox">Red<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="red-checkbox"
          id="red"
          value="red"
          checked
        />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox green">
        <label for="checkbox">Green<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="green-checkbox"
          id="green"
          value="green"
          checked
        />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox colourless">
        <label for="checkbox">Colourless<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="colourless-checkbox"
          id="colourless"
          value="colourless"
          checked
        />
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox multicoloured">
        <label for="checkbox">Multicoloured<span>:</span></label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="Multicoloured-checkbox"
          id="multicoloured"
          value="multi-coloured"
          checked
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <label for="types">Card Types<span>:</span></label>
    <div class="select">
      <select id="type">
        <option name="-" id="-" value="-">-</option>
        <option name="land" id="lands" value="land">Lands</option>
        <option name="creature" id="creatures" value="creature">Creatures</option>
        <option name="planeswalker" id="planeswalkers" value="planeswalker">Planeswalkers</option>
        <option name="instant" id="instants" value="instant">Instants</option>
        <option name="sorcery" id="sorceries" value="sorcery">Sorceries</option>
        <option name="enchantment" id="enchantments" value="enchantment">Enchantments</option>
        <option name="artifact" id="artifacts" value="artifact">Artifacts</option>
        <option name="token" id="tokens" value="token">Tokens</option>
      </select>
      <p>↓</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP card container:

```
<div class="card-container" id="card-container">
  <?php foreach($cards as $card): ?>
    <div class="card colour-<?php echo $card['colour']; ?> type-<?php echo $card['card_type']; ?>" name="<?php echo $card['card_type']; ?>">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="../img/card.png" alt="magic the gathering playing card" />
        <div class="description">
          <div class="name-price">
            <p>
              <?php if(strlen($card['name']) < 10): ?>
              <?php echo $card['name']; ?>
              <?php else: ?>
              <?php echo substr($card['name'], 0, 6) . '...'; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
            <p><?php echo $card['colour'] . $card['card_type']; ?></p>
            <p>
              <?php echo $card['price'] >= 1 ? '£' : ''; ?>
              <?php echo $card['price']; ?>
              <?php echo $card['price'] < 1 ? 'p' : ''; ?>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="stock">
            <p><?php echo $card['stock'] > 0 ? 'In' : 'Out'; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $card['stock'] > 0 ? 'Stock' : 'of Stock'; ?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button id="add-cart-btn" 
          <?php if($card['stock'] === '0'): ?>
            class="card-btn-disabled" disabled
          <?php else: ?> class="card-btn" <?php endif; ?>>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <p>
          <?php echo '<span>Name</span>:<br>' . $card['name']; ?>
          <?php if(strlen($card['description']) < 135): ?>
          <?php echo '<br><br><span>Description</span>:<br>' . $card['description']; ?>
          <?php else: ?>
          <?php echo '<br><br><span>Description</span>:<br>' . substr($card['description'], 0, 135) . '...' . '<button id="more-btn">More<span>...</span></button>'; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

jQuery (messiest code ever written but it works):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // card colours
  const redCard = $('*.colour-red');
  const blueCard = $('*.colour-blue');
  const blackCard = $('*.colour-black');
  const whiteCard = $('*.colour-white');
  const greenCard = $('*.colour-green');
  const colourlessCard = $('*.colour-colourless');
  const multicolouredCard = $('*.colour-multicoloured');

  // card types
  const landCard = $('*.type-land');
  const creatureCard = $('*.type-creature');
  const planeswalkerCard = $('*.type-planeswalker');
  const instantCard = $('*.type-instant');
  const sorceryCard = $('*.type-sorcery');
  const enchantmentCard = $('*.type-enchantment');
  const artifactCard = $('*.type-artifact');
  const tokenCard = $('*.type-token');
  const allCards = $('*.card');

  function refineColour(colourCheckbox, colourCard, type) {
    // value of the card-type dropdown
    let select = $('#type').val();

    $(colourCheckbox).click(() => {
      if (!($(colourCheckbox).is(':checked')) && select !== type) {
        $(colourCard).addClass('card-hide').removeClass('card-display');
      } else if ($(colourCheckbox).is(':checked') && select === type) {
        $(colourCard).removeClass('card-hide').addClass('card-display');
      }
    });
  }

  function refineType(type, cardType, colourCheckbox) {
    // value of the card-type dropdown
    let select = $('#type').val();

    if (select === type && $(colourCheckbox).is(':checked')) {
      $(cardType).addClass('card-display').removeClass('card-hide');
      $(`.card[name!='${type}']`).removeClass('card-display').addClass('card-hide');
      $(colourCheckbox).prop('checked', true);
    } else if (select === '-') {
      $(allCards).removeClass('card-hide');
      $('#blue').prop('checked', true);
      $('#red').prop('checked', true);
      $('#black').prop('checked', true);
      $('#white').prop('checked', true);
      $('#green').prop('checked', true);
      $('#colourless').prop('checked', true);
      $('#multicoloured').prop('checked', true);
    }
  }

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'land');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'land');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'land');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'land');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'land');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'land');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'land');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'enchantment');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'enchantment');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'enchantment');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'enchantment');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'enchantment');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'enchantment');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'enchantment');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'sorcery');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'sorcery');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'sorcery');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'sorcery');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'sorcery');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'sorcery');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'sorcery');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'artifact');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'artifact');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'artifact');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'artifact');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'artifact');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'artifact');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'artifact');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'token');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'token');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'token');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'token');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'token');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'token');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'token');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'instant');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'instant');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'instant');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'instant');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'instant');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'instant');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'instant');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'planeswalker');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'planeswalker');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'planeswalker');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'planeswalker');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'planeswalker');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'planeswalker');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'planeswalker');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, 'creature');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, 'creature');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, 'creature');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, 'creature');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, 'creature');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, 'creature');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, 'creature');

  refineColour('#red', redCard, '-');
  refineColour('#blue', blueCard, '-');
  refineColour('#black', blackCard, '-');
  refineColour('#green', greenCard, '-');
  refineColour('#white', whiteCard, '-');
  refineColour('#colourless', colourlessCard, '-');
  refineColour('#multicoloured', multicolouredCard, '-');

  $('#type').change(() => {
    refineType('land', landCard, '#blue');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#blue');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#blue');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#blue');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#blue');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#blue');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#blue');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#blue');

    refineType('land', landCard, '#red');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#red');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#red');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#red');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#red');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#red');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#red');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#red');

    refineType('land', landCard, '#black');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#black');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#black');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#black');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#black');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#black');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#black');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#black');

    refineType('land', landCard, '#green');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#green');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#green');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#green');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#green');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#green');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#green');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#green');

    refineType('land', landCard, '#white');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#white');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#white');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#white');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#white');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#white');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#white');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#white');

    refineType('land', landCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#colourless');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#colourless');

    refineType('land', landCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('creature', creatureCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('artifact', artifactCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('sorcery', sorceryCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('enchantment', enchantmentCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('token', tokenCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('instant', instantCard, '#multicoloured');
    refineType('planeswalker', planeswalkerCard, '#multicoloured');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card-hide {
  display: none;
}

.card-display {
  display: block;
}
```

If anyone can decipher this and even just point me in the right direction it will be such a huge help.

Comment: I'm doing some quick guesswork here, but I feel like the problem might be in you using the same `.card-hide` class to hide/unhide the items. So if you have a green land, `red land filter` combination could add the hide class because it's not a red card, but then the class would get removed because a green card is still a land. So you would be better off adding a different hide class for color, type, etc...

Comment: That's a good idea I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Mahatmasamatman Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Eh, thought I nailed it :)